# ¿Como hacer multiples sentencias sql desde java? -cerrado

Tags: java, mysql

[![ ][1]]

este código me ejecuta una sola sentencia sql.

```
public Connection getConnexion(String query){
Connection cnx = null;
try{
Class.forName(driver);
PreparedStatement ps= null;
cnx = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
ps = cnx.prepareStatement-(query);
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
System.out.printline("ejecutado correactamente");
}catch(SQLExeption ex){System.out.printline(ex.toString);}
catch(Exeption e){System.out.printline(e.toString);}
return cnx;
```

}

como se puede ejecutar varias sentencias a la vez.quiero ejecutar múltiples sentencias asi:

```
query = "créate database base ; use base ; créate table msg(id      char(8),nombre varchar(10),primary key(id)); "
```

desde java[1]

[1]:

Comment: amigo te saludo y te doy la bienvenida; para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad y te puedan apoyar te sugiero agregar el código en vez de la imagen saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo los principios de la [programación orientada a objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/), podrías [encapsular](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) una clase manager para que se encargue de las conexiones y las consultas, además del cierre correcto de las mismas. Por ejemplo:

### MySQLManager:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MySQLManager {

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String database;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    public MySQLManager(String host, String port, String database, String user, String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.database = database;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private Connection createConnection() {
        Connection connection;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, user,
                    password);
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to MySQL server! because: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("JDBC Driver not found!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
        Connection connection = createConnection();
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet set = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            set = statement.executeQuery(query);
            return set;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { // Close in order: ResultSet, Statement, Connection.
            try {
                set.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void executeUpdate(String update) {
        Connection connection = createConnection();
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(update);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### PruebaConexion:

Finalmente, te puedes encargar de realizar tus acciones solamente ingresando los parametros correctos y dejando que la clase se encargue del resto.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class PruebaConexion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySQLManager manager = new MySQLManager("localhost", "3306", "mydatabase", "user", "pass");
        manager.executeUpdate("create database if not exists base");
        manager.executeUpdate("use base");
        manager.executeUpdate("create table if not exists msg (id int primary key auto_increment, nombre varchar(45))");
        //crear n tablas...

        //Queries
        String sql = "select * from msg";
        ResultSet rs = manager.executeQuery(sql);
    }

}
```

como extra, si quieres realizar alguna acción con tus resultados, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
while (result.next()) {

    Product product = new Product();

    product.setTotal(result.getDouble("Total"));
    product.setName(result.getString("Name"));
    // etc.

    productList.add(product);
}
```

La receta es la misma, solamente debes adecuarlo a tu problema.

---

### MultipleQueries:

Ignorando todo lo anterior, puedes modificar el parámetro AllowMultipleQueries
para permitir queries separadas por coma. Adecuando un pequeño ejemplo, probando en mi equipo, podrías implementar algo así:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


public class MultipleQueriesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "pass";
        Properties props =  new Properties();
        props.put("user",userName);
        props.put("password",password);
        props.put("allowMultiQueries","true");
        Connection conn = null;

        Class.forName(driver);
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);            

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate( "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS facturacion; USE facturacion;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tclientes; CREATE TABLE tclientes ( idcliente VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', nombre VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (idcliente) ) COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB" );

        System.out.println("Tabla tclientes creada existosamente");



    }

}
```

### Output:

```
Tabla tclientes creada existosamente
```

### Verificación Existencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, pero nesecito  ejecutar  muchas sentencias como esto o habra alguna forma de que todo entre en un solo String y se ejecute :                                                                                                                         
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS facturacion;
   USE facturacion;

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tclientes;
  CREATE TABLE tclientes (
   idcliente VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   nombre VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idcliente)
  ) COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: Es posible, y editar mi respuesta para añadir multiqueries. Pero antes, puedo preguntar la razón?

Comment: @AyrtonAxel He añadido un extra, para ingresar multiples sentencias en un solo string.

Comment: gracias @Rcordoval es exactamente lo que queria.

Comment: Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada dando click en el icono de aceptar(check) que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas. Toma en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de programadores y en el futuro podría ser de gran ayuda.